# Is there anybody did install properly aws-cli v2(x86_64; zipped) on Raspberry pi 3(ARM)?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, aws-cli

Is there anybody to try to put aws-cliv2 into raspberry pi?
I've got an err msg below which expresses an exec format error.

---

[my env]
(uname on my Raspberry Pi3)
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.97-v7+ #1294 SMP Thu XXX XX XX:XX:XX GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

[err msg]
**pi@raspberrypi**:~/XX/cdkContainer $ sudo ./aws/install
./aws/install: 78: ./aws/install: /XX/cdkContainer/aws/dist/aws: Exec format error
You can now run: /usr/local/bin/aws --version

**pi@raspberrypi**:~/XX/cdkContainer $ aws --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/aws: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

---

I've just referred to an [aws doc on the web site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html): 
However, It doesn't work on my Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: You cannot execute x86 binaries on an ARM system without an emulator. You'll either have to find or (cross-)compile the program for ARM, or run it in an emulator, which will probably be very slow.

Comment: @tttapa Thank you for your quick response! And I got it...

Comment: So, I found aws-cli for python. I'm gonna try installing it ...

Answer (score 7):

Same here..AWS Cli 2.0 docu page reports ARM, but only for 64 bit architecture, so you cannot use in raspbian.
The only solution I found is to install aws-cli version 1 using pip.

```
python3 -m pip install aws-cli
```

Everything works.

Comment: Thank you for replying!  
We've already gotten a cutting edge version to deal with this issue :)  
I mean that we can use aws cli v2 on raspbian :D  
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/developer/aws-cli-v2-now-available-for-linux-arm/

Comment: above msg to @rok

Comment: @shlbalnu42 - that blog post is not correct. Downloading the awscli-exe-linux-aarch64.zip, extracting and running sudo ./aws/install on Raspbian produces the same "Exec format error".

Comment: Exactly.. because Raspbian is not a 64 bit OS.. so there's no way that a 64bit binary can work there.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html#install-linux-bundled "Install and uninstall the AWS CLI version 1 on Linux using the bundled installer" install successfully on raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit). Version 2 fails.

Comment: Eventually: `pip install awscli`

Answer (score 1):

Had the problem on Raspberry 5.0 when installing AWS CLI v2:
"aws: Exec format error".
It was solved with the help of snap. On a Raspberry Pi running the latest version of Raspbian snap can be installed directly from the command line:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install snapd
```

Reboot your device:

```
$sudo reboot
```

Install the core snap in order to get the latest snapd:

```
$ sudo snap install core
```

Install **aws-cli v2**:

```
$ sudo snap install aws-cli --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

aws-cli v2 only supports 64-bit ARM, and your Raspberry Pi is presumably 32-bit, so it looks like what you're asking is simply impossible. The older aws-cli v1 does support Raspberry Pi though.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5426) on Github where a dev confirmed the issue, but they currently have no fix planned.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing I think as others mentioned is that you are perhaps running the 64-bit aws-cli version. I ran into this issue on my linux machine running an arm processor. The easiest solution was installing the linux arm version instead (see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).

If you already have a 64-bit version installed, you can just delete the 64-bit file, download the arm version and re-run the installation with an update flag:

sudo ./aws/install --update

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Users

For those comming with a newly installed `WSL` Linux Ubuntu, you need to install `pip` python module and then install `awscli` :

```bash
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip install awscli
```

Then add the installed bin in your `PATH` (replace `<MY_USER>` with yours) :

- zsh :

  ```bash
  echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/<MY_USER>/.local/bin" >> ~/.zshrc
  ```
- bash :

  ```bash
  echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/<MY_USER>/.local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
  ```

Finally check everything is good :

```bash
➜ aws --version
aws-cli/1.29.8 Python/3.10.6 Linux/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 botocore/1.31.8
```